# OpenGLES in a Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, c++, opengl-es, windows-phone-8.1

I have a C++ lib that draws visual controls on a drawing context using OpenGLES  (like buttons, textboxes, lists etc.). I want to use this lib on multiple mobile devices (Windows Phone 8.1, IoS, Android).

Right now I want to try to use it on a Windows Phone, so I want to:

1. integrate this library into a Windows Phone 8.1 application
2. send the drawing context of the Windows phone app to the C++ code in order to draw on it.

Could you give me a few directions how to do this?

Thank you,
Nadia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) to run your OpenGL ES code on Windows Phone 8.1.

See the [Build session ANGLE: Running OpenGL ES 2.0 Graphics Code on Windows](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-686) for more details and the [MSOpenTech ANGLE wiki](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/angle/wiki) for sample code and tutorials.